# How can pull an attribute that is associated with a user in the template?

Tags: django, templates, view, model

I am trying to get an image associated with a user to display properly.  I need help determining what should be included in the template.  Specifically, I think the code in the template "{{review.user__image}} is incorrect.  Based on a particular review and the user that has written that review, how do I pull in the image associated with the user?

## views.py

```
def view_reviews(request, product_name):
    product = get_object_or_404(Productbackup, url_friendly=product_name)
    product_id = product.id
    reviews = Reviewbackup.objects.filter(product_id=product_id).order_by("-created_on")
    return render_to_response('reserve/templates/view_reviews.html', {'reviews':reviews},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

## models.py

```
class Reviewbackup(models.Model):
    review = models.CharField('Review', max_length = 2000)
    user = models.CharField('Username', max_length =  200)
    rating = models.IntegerField(max_length=2, choices=RATING_OPTIONS)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Productbackup)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.review

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, primary_key=True)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=255, upload_to="images/")
```

## template

```
{% for review in reviews %} 
    <br><a href = "/user/{{review.user}}/">{{review.user}}</a><br>
    <img class = "thumbnail" src = "http://test.webfactional.com/static/{{review.user__image}}"><br>
    {{review}}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for long answer. Judging by your code, I assume you are new to Django, so this answer hopefully will be informative as well as in the process answer question.

## User

In your review model, `user` should be a `ForeignKey` instead of a `CharField`. I understand that it seems more natural to store a username, especially if you will be looking at the database table yourself, however that approach is error-prone and unless you have a very good reason, a bad thing to do.

Imagine you have a user whose username is `foousername`. Then that user creates a couple of reviews. So at this point you will have a couple of reviews where the `user` field will be `foousername`. Now if the user will want to change his/her username to `someotherfoousername`, in order not to break the link between reviews and the user, you will have to change `user` field for all the reviews which the user created to use the new username. That is an extra step, which you might forget to do, therefore it is error prone. Using `ForeignKey` solves this issue right away. Even if the user changes his/her username, the primary id of the user will not change, so if reviews link to primary keys (which is what foreign key is), reviews do not have to be updated. So less work, and more reliable method.

So do this (will explain `related_name` next):

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='reviews')
```

## `related_name`

When you are using `related_name`, Django makes your life a lot easier.

Consider your view. First you query the product. Then once you get it, you take it's id and then you construct a query which will return all reviews for that product. Using Django you can do all of that using much less code.

```
product = get_object_or_404(Productbackup, url_friendly=product_name)
reviews = product.reviewbackup_set.all()
```

This however is a bit confusing because of the whole `_set` business. This is where `related name` comes in. If you define your `product` field as follows:

```
product = models.ForeignKey(Productbackup, related_name='reviews')
```

then you can do the same in a bit more readable way (and Python should be readable...):

```
reviews = product.reviews.all()
```

## User's profile

Foreign keys allow to implement one-to-many relationships. So for products and reviews it makes perfect sense. One product can have many reviews. However usually that is not the case for user profiles. Usually a user has only one user profile. So within your user profile, you should not have `ForeignKey` to a user, but instead should use `OneToOneField` like so:

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True, related_name='profile')
```

That allows you to easily access user's profile:

```
user_profile = User.objects.get(...).profile
```

## User's image

For each review, now since the user is `ForeignKey` as per my first explanation, you can access user's image very easily:

```
review = Reviewbackup.objects.all()[0]
user_image = review.user.profile.image   # <- see, very easy
```

## Image URL

Whenever you use `FileField` in Django, it uploads the files into `upload_to` place under your media folder - the one defined in `MEDIA_ROOT` in your project settings. So in your case, Django will store images in `images` folder within your media folder. In addition, if you configure `MEDIA_URL`, that allows to access file's url like:

```
user_profile.image.url
```

## Hard-coded URLs

Its a very bad idea to include direct urls within your templates. Thats what url pattern names are for. So the idea is that you assign to url pattern a name, so that later on you get the url by referencing a name. That makes the code much more maintainable. For example, the following is a url-pattern for a user:

```
url(r'^user/(?P<username>\w+)/$', 'user_view', name='user_view')
```

This allows you to use it like so in templates:

```
{% load url from future %}
link: <a href="{% url 'user_view' username=user.username %}">{{ user.username }}</a>
```

## Putting everything together

```
# views.py
def view_reviews(request, product_name):
    product = get_object_or_404(Productbackup, url_friendly=product_name)
    reviews = product.reviews.all().order_by("-created_on")
    return render_to_response('reserve/templates/view_reviews.html',
                              {'reviews':reviews},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and

```
# models.py
class Reviewbackup(models.Model):
    review = models.CharField('Review', max_length = 2000)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='reviews')
    rating = models.IntegerField(max_length=2, choices=RATING_OPTIONS)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Productbackup, related_name='reviews')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.review

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True, related_name='profile')
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=255, upload_to="images/")
```

and

```
{# template #}
{% load url from future %}
{% for review in reviews %} 
    <br><a href="{% url user_view username=review.user.username %}">
        {{ review.user.username }}</a><br>
    <img class="thumbnail" src="{{ review.user.profile.image.url }}"><br>
    {{ review.review }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer!  When I change user from CharField to ForeignKey, I get an error when I run the migration (I'm using South): The following SQL query failed: CREATE INDEX "reserve_reviewbackup_fbfc09f1" ON "reserve_reviewbackup" ("user_id");
The error was: index reserve_reviewbackup_fbfc09f1 already exists
 ! Error found during real run of migration! Aborting.

 ! Since you have a database that does not support running
 ! schema-altering statements in transactions, we have had 
 ! to leave it in an interim state between migrations.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Don't know how to fix it though. How much data you have in the db? If development db/deployment, you can just start from scratch (do syncdb from scratch), make sure the new db schema works properly, and then after all of debugging and bug fixing, migrate old data.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't know how to get your user profile.  Here is some information on how to define a UserProfile so it will work:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users

In short, you'd make UserProfile.user a OneToOneField, and then you'd be able to use user.get_profile().  Otherwise, you can leave your model definition as is, and use something like `UserProfile.objects.get(user=user)` or `user.userprofile_set.all()[0]` (eww).

Once you have your UserProfile object, @Ignacio is quite right.  The image is on there.  I suspect the problem with `{{ review.user.userprofile.image }}` is that since user is a ForeignKey instead of a OneToOneField your User instead carries a `userprofile_set` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  You mentioned that I can use UserProfile.objects.get(user=user) if I use the current model, but I don't think I can use this in the template right?  I'm not selecting an individual user; I'm selecting multiple reviews and then getting the user for each of those reviews.  For example, {{review.user}} works fine when I put it in the template.  Why doesn't {{review.user.userprofile.image}}?  Why would that work with OneToOne but not ForeignKey?

Comment: If the relationship was defined as a OneToOne, then you would have a singular `userprofile` attribute on the User for a reverse relation. Since it is instead a ForeignKey (many profiles could point at the same User), you get a `userprofile_set` attribute which yields a queryset.

Comment: With no `userprofile` attribute on your User, {{review.user.userprofile}}, {{review.user.userprofile.image}}, and {{review.user.userprofile.whatever_else}} all result in ''. Django templates are forgiving to a fault in that respect.

Answer (score -1):

`image` is not on `User`, it's on `UserProfile`.

```
{{ review.user.userprofile.image }}
```

Comment: I tried {{review.user.userprofile.image}} but it's not working.